# Clear items selected from ListBox

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I am trying to create a simple form using an Excel macro. This form will be used to input data which will be stored in Sheet2.  Once the data has been saved, I would like to clear the contents from the form.  I have been able to achieve this for most of the input boxes except for listbox.  Below is the code that through which I am trying to achieve this functionality.

```
     Dim clearlstbox As Long

      With AOI
       For clearlstbox = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
         If .Selected(clearlstbox) = True Then
        .RemoveItem clearlstbox
         End If
       Next clearlstbox
      End With

   '
   'For clearlstbox = AOI.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
   '    If AOI.Selected(clearlstbox) = True Then
   '        AOI.RemoveItem (clearlstbox)
   '    End If
   'Next
```

With both the codes it throws a similar error message "runtime error '-2147467259 (80004005) unspecified error"

Comment: Do you want to actually remove the selected items from the list box or just deselect them?

Comment: deselect them from the listbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To deselect all the items in a list box

```
For clearlstbox = 0 To AOI.ListCount - 1
    AOI.Selected(clearlstbox) = False
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

You can deselect any selected values in a listbox by running this:

```
Me.Listbox1.Value = ""
```

where "Listbox1" is the name of your listbox

To clear a multiselect listbox, use this code:

```
Me.listbox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectSingle
Me.listbox1.Value = ""
Me.listbox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
```

this sets it to a single select to clear it, then back to a multiselect for your original functionality

Comment: Is there a way to select all items as simple as unselecting? And for .value = "" to work wouldn't .BoundColumn have to be set to 0 as well?